# Got exception in create run time editText object

Tags: android, android-edittext

I attempt to create an `EditText` object at run time this way:

```
EditText et=new EditText(MyActivity.this);
```

And i have got below exception in Samsung galaxy tab in other tablet it works fine.

```
android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager$1.<init>(ClipboardExManager.java:90)
android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager.<init>(ClipboardExManager.java:89)
android.app.ContextImpl$8.createService(ContextImpl.java:292)
android.app.ContextImpl$ServiceFetcher.getService(ContextImpl.java:199)
android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:1158)
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:79)
android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3932)
android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:68)
android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:62)
android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:58)
```

`com.example.myProject.MyActivity.insertTextBox(MyActivity.java:8249)
com.example.myProject.MyActivity$19.run(com.example.myProject.MyActivity.java:8057)`

Comment: That does not seem like the complete logcat, can you post the complete logcat?

Comment: It might also help to specify what `this` is and what it extends, as well as what android versions the tablets have

Comment: this class is extends Activity and tablet have android 3.2 version(API Level 13) and i have write MyActivity.this instead of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve this issue just by adding one view from xml layout which visually gone and than add all view runtime in linearlayout and its works fine. I don't know what's the issue but it's solve.

Answer (score 1):

You should really post more code for the problem to become apparent.

Based on the little information you provided my guess is you tried to create that `EditText` before the context is initialized.

Try to move that code in the `onCreate()` method if it's not already there.